# LINQ - IQueryable optimization - is it needed?

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, iqueryable

Let's say we have a form with few checkboxes (similar reports let's say - based on the same table, but different filters).

i have a method which takes few parameters - 3 of them are common for every report, 3 of them are specific for a report. Simplified version:

```
public IEnumerable<ReportSet> GetAList(DateTime commonDate, bool commonBoolean, TypeEnum mainReportType, AnotherTypeEnum sideType)
{
  IQueryable<ReportSet> aList = this.DB.Reports;

  aList = aList.FilterByDate(commonDate);
  aList = aList.FilterByBool(commonBoolean);

  switch(mainReportType)
  {
    case 1:
       aList = aList.Where(x=>x..)
       break;
    case 2:  
       aList = aList.Where(x=>x..)
       break;
  }

 return aList;
}
```

if all checkboxes will be checked i have to make firts part of the method several Times (so obtaining from db and 2 filterBy), but i'd have to use some Tuple as i need a set of parameters for each report specific parameters and foreach tuple call private method with the switch part i guess.

I can make it but is it worth making it as those filters are on one part on iqueryable only? (obtaining data from DB will be done few Times in any case).

Any advice?

EDIT: based on the answer below that's my plan:
I'll take all filters, build one query which get all wanted data to fill all checked list (but no more), than go to the DB (only once as going to db is the most cost here i guess so i want to do this only once), than split the result to the list i need in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your question, but LINQ2SQL (or any LINQ for that matter) will only evaluate when needed, not directly on the statement / assignment.

It's called [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)!

So in your example, you're just building a (giant) query, and with a ToList() or a foreach, it will evaluate all that you stacked together, generate a big SQL statement and pass it to the database for evaluation.

You can check this behavior when you enable the logging to the generated SQL statements:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961(v=vs.110).aspx

```
db.Log = Console.Out;
IQueryable<Customer> custQuery =
    from cust in db.Customers
    where cust.City == "London" 
    select cust;

foreach(Customer custObj in custQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(custObj.CustomerID);
}
```

generates:

```
SELECT [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[CompanyName], [t0].[ContactName], [t0].[ContactT
itle], [t0].[Address], [t0].[City], [t0].[Region], [t0].[PostalCode], [t0].[Coun
try], [t0].[Phone], [t0].[Fax]
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[City] = @p0
-- @p0: Input String (Size = 6; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [London]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2005) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.20810.0
```

Comment: That's brilliant idea - thanks, i've just learned something new and awesome :) I will split and execute one query and then - do .where in c# to split it to the list i want to.